# Are ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1files required when migrating MySQL to another new server?

Tags: mysql, database, migration

I am migrating MySQL from an existing server running MySQL 5.0 to a new server running 5.6. The source database is using MyISAM and INNODB engine. It has innodb_file_per_table parameter enabled.

I have copied all the user database data files from source server to the destination server. MySQL and Performance schema database is not copied.

I am not sure if I should copy ibdata1, ib_logile0, ib_logfile1 over or I should just use the default ones that already created in the destination server when I first installed MySQL 5.6?

I have to result to copying instead of binary dump using mysqldump and restore the database is huge at 4TB. I do not have a long downtime for the source DB and mysqldump will lock the tables for longer than a copying.

Comment: Upon copying all files including ibdata1, ib_logfile0. MySQL crashed and unable to startup.
key_buffer_size=xxx
read_buffer_size=xxx
max_threads=xx
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 33310707 K  Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/app/mysql/mysql/bin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x90f695]

Answer (score 1):

You are contemplating an advanced operation, which requires considerable expertise, because it is in fact an upgrade directly from 5.0 to 5.6, which *might* work, but **is not supported**.

The recommended path is to upgrade through each major release, 5.0 to 5.1 to 5.5 to 5.6.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html

Yes, you need the system tablespace (ibdata1) and to avoid getting your server into an inconsistent state, you also should retain the ib_log* files *as well as* a my.cnf with settings compatible with those log files.

Dumping and reloading is a better (safer) approach than a binary (file copy) migration, but even then you may need to handle the "mysql" schema manually, due to structural changes across versions.  Loading a 5.0 dump directly onto a 5.6 server *might* work, if you immediately run `mysql_upgrade` after loading the dump file, to bring the system tables up to date, since loading the 5.0 dump onto a new server will mangle them.

Proceed with caution.

Answer (score -1):

You may clean ib_logile0, ib_logfile1 but not ibdata1. ibdata1 file contains the innodb data where as ib_logile* contains the logs.

Also check the MySql documentation whether coping data files between major releases are advisable? I think it is better if you can get a dump and restore because there are some structural differences. In this way you may get some data issues.

Comment: You'll notice in the MySQL documentation that there is no cleaning on ib_logfile0/1.